# How to include dependencies in android library gradle project?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-library

I'm building an android library project with Gradle using Android Studio. It has some local dependencies:

`compile project(':androidlibrary')`

with nested, additional external dependencies:

`compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '14.0.1'`

I managed to build the `aar` file but no external or local dependencies are included. I expect external dependencies to be mentioned in the POM file when published to maven, but what about the local ones?

What is the right way to build such project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using "download library from maven" feature of **Intellj IDEA** as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html). It downloads the library and all it's dependencies to the local directory.

Just a friendly warning: including dependencies is considered a very bad practice at SHOULD BE AVOIDED. It may cause conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

There is no automated way to package the dependencies of the library inside the aar. This is contrary to proper dependency management and can lead to problems down the line.

If you really want to do this, you'd have to gather the dependencies manually (using code in build.gradle) and manually package the files in the aar.

Comment: Anywhere i can find the code to gather the dependencies manually and package the files in aar? I have the same specific question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149359/android-gradle-dependency